# How to get min_value/max_value/default_value from Blender Node input? For example Background node Strength input?

Tags: python, shader-nodes

I am trying to get 3 values from input of the background node of the world.

I'm looking through the API but can't find anything about it.
Usually this can be read the input values from a node  group like this example:

```
scn = C.scene
world = scn.world
node_tree = world.node_tree
nodes = node_tree.nodes

my_node_group = nodes['my_node_group']

socket = my_node_group.node_tree.inputs[0]

min_value = socket.min_value
max_value = socket.max_value
default_value = socket.default_value
```

Is really simple with node group, but with a standard node like Background Node, im not able to grab this values.

Any idea?

Background Strength input value have this values:

```
min_value = 0
max_value = 1000000
default_value = 1
```

[image]

To understand better, it is sufficient to create a group node containing only the Background Node, it will automatically connect to the node_groups input node (node_tree) then it will actually show the default values of the Background node, within the group node:

[image]

At the moment I am creating a script that iterates all existing Blender nodes and creates a group on them, and from the group node I get the real values of min_value, max_value, default_value of the Blender node. I can write them in a Json file, but it's not very nice practice, as the blender versions change and with it the nodes and sockets too

Comment: uhm...i am sorry, but also with a "normal material" e.g. principled bsdf you cannot read min-max value the way you described it. That's simply not true. The only thing you can get is default_value. And this you can read from background node as well. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc1bx.png

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately your example is incorrect. Since not even from the group node you will be able to get the min_value and the max_value in that way. In addition, the default_value you get directly from the input in this way is the current value and not the default one. I know it sounds confusing, but I invite you to test on a group node

Comment: ok, but am i wrong, but you did want to read that values from the background node, which isn't a group node, right? or did i misunderstand that too? you are right - i just focused to your title of the question.

Comment: Hey, no problem, I just wanted to be specific (Hope useful). Somewhere Blender nodes have a minimum, maximum and default value. I don't know where, but I'm not in node.default_value, as that is the current value. I used the example with the group node, since it all the default values can be found from the node_tree.inputs[0].default_value etc.

Comment: i am pretty sure the values are in the property. Like you have floatproperty, and then you can additionally add min, max and default value. But i cannot prove that, but maybe a PRO can ;)